# IPTables Configuration to allow all connections, only close/deny once data is sent

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I'm looking to set up my IPTables firewall in such a way that:

- Any new `connect()` is accepted
- Once data is received:

  - If the destination port is on a whitelist, continue allowing the connection and any `RELATED` connections
  - Otherwise, close/reset the connection

---

I've looked around, and even tried a few configurations of my own, but I'm not very familiar with IPTables, and haven't had success. My first attempt was like so:

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -I lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT //example of allowed port
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Which as I understand should perform the following:

- Accept all localhost traffic
- Accept all `NEW` connections
- Accept all traffic to port `22`
- Drop all traffic not handled by port `22` rule
- (Set default rules for `INPUT`, `FORWARD`, and `OUTPUT` chains)

However, connections to port 22 still fail on `connect()`. Ideally, communication with `22` should be unhindered, and `connect()` to any other port succeeds, but then the connection is closed once `send(...)` is called.

Comment: Have you used `iptables -vnL` to look at the counters and possibly put in `-j LOG` statements to see what rule gets hit when? I suppose there is a service listening on port 22? :)

Comment: I have not yet - I suspect that what I'm describing is not possible. I don't think IPTables is capable of accepting connections itself (just filtering them). I think that if no service is listening on a port, `connect()` will fail, even if IPTables allows the connection attempt through.

Comment: Of course `connect()` will fail if there is nothing listening. iptables is a packet filter, not a connection endpoint.

Comment: Using `haproxy` in TCP mode will do alot of what you want.  You can have it listen on all the ports you are interested in and redirect to real services on a different set of ports or an internal IP.

Answer (score 3):

Your setup will probably do what you want, *once you have a service listening on the concerned port(s)*. Iptables is a packet filter, not a connection endpoint.